# plotting negative and positive numbers bar python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've created function to calculate the percentage of delay and over achieve
in percentage for multiple staff but I don't know how to visualize it

**For example** :

John : (60.0,40.0)  # 60.0 delay and 40 percent over achieve

Ellen : (45.0,55.0)

how can i visualize it like the picture attached 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame([(60,40), (45, 55)], columns=['delay', 'overachive'], 
                  index=['John', 'Ellen'])
df['delay'] = -df['delay']
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Man for the help really  appreciate it :)